# Function to return the letter of a cell-address from a range

Tags: vba, excel

I need an excel macro that can return the letter of a cell-address from a range.

For example, if I have two worksheets, I would like to use it on worksheet2 but it should find me the letter of a cell in worksheet1.
Something like:

=Letter(sheet1!A1:sheet1!D6;"cat";"not found")

So in this case, it would has to search for "cat" in A1:D6 in sheet1 and if it has found it, it would return me the letter as value, like "C", "not found" if it couldn't find it.

I already searched for it and found some similar but I don't really know VBA and was not able to adapt something.

Can someone help me out?

Comment: Why?  Are you going to use that information for another formula?

Comment: If you mean the column of the result, why would you ever need to do that?

Comment: Yes, for an indirect formula in a third worksheet.
So basically sheet1 = data, sheet2=paths, sheet3=basis table and everything else build itself out of sheet3

Comment: Then you can skip that and go directly to the  end with INDEX.  If you give us the full picture and we can help with the correct formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Function Letter(Target As Range, Search As Variant, value_if_false As Variant)
    Dim f As Range
    Set f = Target.Find(Search, After:=Target.Cells(1), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    If f Is Nothing Then
        Letter = value_if_false
    Else
        Letter = Split(f.Address(True, True), "$")(1)
    End If
End Function
```